# Cannot access value from function node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access what a function returns in node.js

I have the following function:

```
function getImg(callback) {
  https.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=api-key', response => {
    let data = "";
    response.on('data', chunk => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
      let img = JSON.parse(data).hdurl;
      callback(null, img);

    })

  }).end();

}
let image = getImg(function(err, image) {
  console.log(image);

})

res.render('index', {
  indexCSS: true,
  image
})
```

It can log it to the console correctly, but if I want to access the value of the variable like I do in the last line of my code or if I `console.log(image)` I get `undefined`.

What have I done wrong. How can I access what the function produces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a callback style function which wouldn't return any thing. Better to convert it to promise sttyle and use `async/await` to get the value in a variable

```
function getImg() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=api-key', response => {
      let data = "";
      response.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
      });
      response.on('end', () => {
        let img = JSON.parse(data).hdurl;
        resolve(img);
      })

    }).end();
  });


}

(async() => {
  let image = await getImg();

  res.render('index', {
    indexCSS: true,
    image
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really store the return value of your function like that. Unfortunately JS is non-blocking, so the code will continue to execute past it, before it has a chance to return that value from the https request. I am not sure exactly when you call this function, but you could call `res.render` in the callbacks response after calling getImg() without assigning its value to something. You can use promises, otherwise it's better to handle the response you need when it is returned from the callback. That would just be a simple call like:

```
getImg(function(err, image) {
  res.render('index', {
    indexCSS: true,
    image
  });
})
```

Within whatever route is calling this function. You just cannot assign any kind of return value from a callback to a variable (really not recommended at least) in the normal way.